# Increase displacement resolution / smooth vertices in SceneKit tessellated mesh

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to generate a mesh from a depth/displacement map using SceneKit

The source depth map I'm using looks like this:
[image: depth map]

I then generate a plane with an increased segment count and heavily tessellate it and apply the displacement material. Here's the code I'm using:

```swift
import Cocoa
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// MARK: - View setup

let scene = SCNScene()

let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 1000
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light!.type = .omni
lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor.darkGray
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

let scnView = SCNView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
scnView.scene = scene
scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
scnView.showsStatistics = true
scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = scnView

// MARK: - Plane

let plane = SCNPlane(width: 200, height: 200)
plane.widthSegmentCount = 10
plane.heightSegmentCount = 10

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
planeNode.name = "Plane"
planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.white

let tessellator = SCNGeometryTessellator()
tessellator.tessellationFactorScale = 25
tessellator.tessellationPartitionMode = .pow2
tessellator.insideTessellationFactor = 4
tessellator.edgeTessellationFactor = 4
tessellator.smoothingMode = .phong

planeNode.geometry?.tessellator = tessellator

planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.displacement.contents = "rabbit"
planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.displacement.textureComponents = .red
planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.displacement.intensity = 200
planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.displacement.maxAnisotropy = 1
planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.displacement.magnificationFilter = .none

planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .phong

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

Which mostly gives me the 3D mesh I'm aiming for:

[image: tessellation + displacement]

But the resulting "blockiness" messes with the lighting. Wireframe view shows it clearer:

[image: wireframe]

Is there any way to "smoothen" the resulting mesh, average vertex positions, or something similar?
I'm very tangentially familiar with 3D and basically unfamiliar with SceneKit and google/docs haven't yielded much.

Subdivision / adaptive subdivision doesn't solve the problem, neither does increasing tessellation detail to the highest count possible. It can make the shadow/highlight patches smaller, but they're still there.

Any help or pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!
The ladder effect is an artifact of 8-bit banding in the depth map
Converting the image to 32-bit depth and adding a slight blur pretty much fixed it:

[image]

Comment: Wow, are you running this on Mac or IOS device?  I've always had trouble with the displacement maps, mine look even worse than your first one...

Comment: Any ideas how to fix the detail in mine? it's really boxy... https://imgur.com/HkZv2K0